# Popover and Hover

Tags: reactjs, hover, popover

As I was hovering my nav women's category, it somehow only shows men's data under it, when I hover men's catgory, it correctly shows all men's data, but somehow it skipped the women's data when mapping it,  can anyone help me where my code is wrong? also do I need have popover to be open state even if I just hover it ?

```
export default function Example() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState(false);
<Popover.Group>
                <div
                  onMouseEnter={() => setIsShowing(true)}
                  onMouseLeave={() => setIsShowing(false)}
                  
                >
                  {navigation.categories.map((category) => (
                    <Popover key={category.name} className="flex">
                      {({ open }) => ( 
                      {
                        <>
                          <div className="relative flex">
                            <Popover.Button
                              className={classNames(
                               open
                                  ? "border-indigo-600"
                                  : "border-transparent",
                               "relative z-10 flex items-center"
                             )}
                            >
                              {category.name}
                            </Popover.Button>
                          </div>

                          <Transition
                            show={isShowing}
                            onMouseEnter={() => setIsShowing(true)}
                            onMouseLeave={() => setIsShowing(false)}
                           
                     
                          </Transition>
                        </>
                      }
                    </Popover>
                  ))}
```

here is my data:

```
const navigation = {
  categories: [
    {
      id: "women",
      name: "Women",
      featured: [
        {
          name: "New Arrivals",
         }
      {
      id: "men",
      name: "men",
      featured: [
        {
          name: "New Arrivals",
         }]
      ]}
```

Comment: your `navigation` object is wrong, categories, is not an array of objects, if you see the question the same object is having multiple properties for id key

Comment: when I map it like this : navigation.categories.map((category) => (
                    and I return this {category.name}, so it should be mapping through women first and then men, so when I hover it, it should show accordingly......can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Your navigation should look like this. `const navigation = {
  categories: [
    {
      id: "women",
      name: "Women",
      featured: [
        {
          name: "New Arrivals",
         }
       ]
},
      {
      id: "men",
      name: "men",
      featured: [
        {
          name: "New Arrivals",
         }]
}
]
}` here women and men are objects inside an array, only then map will work!

Comment: oh ok I see, let me try that! BTW, do you know why popover group state need to be open even when I hover it? I was looking at this: https://codesandbox.io/s/d8llw?file=/src/App.js and just confused...

Comment: hmmm does not work, it still shows men data only under women's when I hover

Comment: I think the problem is in my code popover and hover , not on my data format

Comment: does this answer solve your issue?